# best way to save Players details for offline game

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, datastore

Im working on a multiplayer turn based game in xcode for iphone/ipad im considering my options when it comes to where to save users details such as name / points ect. I was considering creating a plist and storing data in this also i have considered nsuserdefaults and also core data.

Basically majority of the time the user will be adding new details on every launch however this will not be the case 100% of the time.

What would you guys consider the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on multiple factors:

- How much data is it going to be saved?
- How fast the data needs to be loaded?

I suggest you create a serializable object, that conforms to `NSCoding` protocol. There is also an option to save this as **JSON** or like you noted, **plist**.

I think Core Data is too much boiler plate, if this is all you are storing. `NSUserDefaults` is fast enough and already prepared for you to use.

*I don't think someone can give you the correct answer, I suggest you experiment with all the options and see which one is the best for you.*

Comment: Thanks for such a great response. Im new to objective c and not heared of a json before (better get googling)

Comment: Im thinking a plist or nsdefaults however a tad of research may be good